# Enhance performance of update query

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a query that is running against a table with 50 million rows.  The phone number is stored as a CHAR(10) and an ETL process is changing the phone number if it has certain values.  We are seeing poor performance of this query and was wondering if anyone has any suggestions on improving performance.  No index currently exists with the phone number.

```
UPDATE Table SET phone='' WHERE ( phone IS NULL
              OR phone = ''
              OR phone = '0000000000' 
              OR phone = '0' 
              OR phone like '111%'
              OR phone like '222%'
              OR phone like '333%'
              OR phone like '444%'
              OR phone like '555%'
              OR phone like '666%'
              OR phone like '777%'
              OR phone like '888%'
              OR phone like '999%'
              OR phone like '800%'
              OR phone like '900%' 
            )
```

Comment: Ah, no index in `phone` column, what did you expect?

Comment: Yeah this is a table scan, no way around it if the column isn't indexed.

Comment: Will adding a non-clustered index for phone help as it is a CHAR column?

Comment: Yes, why do you think it would not?

Comment: You're also wasting time by setting phone = '' where phone = ''

Comment: I am curious about how many rows are changing. If only a few,  then no problem.  But if you are changing a significant portion of the 50 million rows you might want to break the update into separate batches. (e.g. change the 111s as one update, then the 222s, etc.) This would give you shorter transactions and fewer blocking issues.

Comment: @RLF I suppose you mean after adding the index. Otherwise, they'll end up with 15 table scans instead of one.

Comment: @ypercube - Yes, I meant with the index.  (Never assume, always state the detail.  Thanks.)

Comment: Same as [this problem](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61132/efficient-way-to-add-non-clustered-index#comment110265_61132), adding an index probably won't help much unless the base table is really wide. The `OR` predicates almost always preclude the possibility of a seek-based plan. The best it will do is scan the non-clustered index instead of the clustered index. That said, creating the index just for the `UPDATE` is pointless if the index isn't needed after the fact; the process of creating the index will table scan anyway.

Comment: @JonSeigel I assumed that the `UPDATE` is run in often intervals.

Comment: Interesting to see what the OP replies after all these comments

Comment: Actually thanks to Mark Sinkinson for pointing out that the ='' is not needed.  It was actually updating 17 million records in that part of the where clause.  So if I take that out it returns very few records quickly.  I think I will still add an index to the column, but removing that will make it much quicker.  Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Considering we talking about ETL process, I consider this like a *muscle hard work* which can involve the table fragmentation, storage options and hardware stress, where all this should be revised and considered as variables at optimization process. I have doubt about create the index because will double the work updating the table and the index (which probably will unbalance the index tree/pages giving a gradually poor performance). Anyway I consider test : Create the index + update individually each filter. This way you will work only over the 17mi rows and not 50mi.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by improve performance.  You can't make that query faster, it needs to scan the table.  But you can keep it from using too many resources and blocking other processes by chunking it, which is essentially iterating through batches of  rows to perform multiple smaller updates.

There must be some option to just write it to the target table instead of updating in place.

You could also forego the scrub altogether and use a non-persisted computed column in the target database to reformat the phone number if you don't need to index it.

Answer (score -1):

Usually when performing DML operations, especially ones that affect a high percentage of rows, it is better to disable the indexes, and rebuild them afterwards. This is because most of them time, the engine is trying to reorganize the index after each DML operation. For INSERT and DELETE, it is obvious that a clustered index will be rebuilt after each row. With UPDATEs you might cause page splits, which again, will force an index rebuild.

Back to your issue, I don't think an index will solve the problem, as long as your condition is set on the updated column, so in the end, all your rows must be tested. In fact, it is better to work directly on the table rather than making roundtrips to the index.

Is there a way to do updating as a nightly job? I'm afraid to you might be limited by the hardware resources. If you are sure that that's not the case, please give me some more details.

Comment: Except the question is about SQL Server, not Oracle.

Comment: Oh yes, missed the tag. Still, in my opinion indexes should be avoided.